# Timeout in VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to add timeout in vbscript. So that where ever the server is not responding/hung script will wait only for a minuet and will continue collecting data from other remote server. But the timeout script below is not working.

Can anyone help me to correct this please ?

```
strComputer=""
timeout=60
Set locator =CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
locator.Security_.ImpersonationLevel=3
Set wmi=locator.ConnectComputer(strSrv,"root\cimv2",,,timeout)
strQuery = "SELECT * from Win32_BIOS"
Set results =wmi.ExecQuery(strQuery)
```

Comment: Does the `SWbemLocator` object even have a `.ConnectComputer()` method? all's I see is `.ConnectServer()` and that doesn't appear to have a timeout argument?

Comment: Actually just tested this code and as I expected the error is `Object doesn't support this property or method: 'locator.ConnectComputer'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use wscript.sleep.

```
Wscript.sleep <miliseconds>
```

Example:

```
Wscript.sleep 60000
```